# backbone.js: different output for same process

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

Working through the `setElement` part of [Addy Osmani's backbone.js tutorial](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#what-is-el).

He presents this example:

```
// We create two DOM elements representing buttons
// which could easily be containers or something else
var button1 = $('<button></button>');
var button2 = $('<button></button>');

// Define a new view
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
      events: {
        click: function(e) {
          console.log(view.el === e.target);
        }
      }
    });

// Create a new instance of the view, applying it
// to button1
var view = new View({el: button1});

// Apply the view to button2 using setElement
view.setElement(button2);

button1.trigger('click'); 
button2.trigger('click');
```

However, he doesn't explain why there is different output for `button1.trigger('click');` vs. `button2.trigger('click');` -- possibly a dumb question, and I know that these are different ways of attaching the view to the button elements, but why does `button2.trigger('click');` also return `true`?

Comment: Backbone is really consistent. ONLY button2 returns true now, not both. the setElement() method changed the element (el) of the view to button2. so button1 does not return anything anymore. Backbone moved everything for you, events included... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`button1.trigger('click');` shouldn't produce any output at all from that code.

[`setElement`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) is fairly simple:

> **setElement** `view.setElement(element)`
>
> If you'd like to apply a Backbone view to a different DOM element, use **setElement**, which will also create the cached `$el` reference and move the view's delegated events from the old element to the new one.

So `view.setElement(e)` does four things:

1. Unbinds the view's `events` from `view.el`.
2. Sets `view.el = e`.
3. Sets `view.$el = Backbone.$(e)`.
4. Binds the view's `events` to the new `view.el`.

The result is that nothing will be left listening to events from `button1` and `view` will be listening to events from `button2`.

A more thorough example might help so let us attach some more click event handlers:

```
var button1 = $('<button id="button1"></button>').click(function() {
    console.log('button1 jQuery', this);
});
var button2 = $('<button id="button2"></button>').click(function() {
    console.log('button2 jQuery', this);
});

var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        click: function(e) {
            console.log('Backbone ', view.el, view.el === e.target);
        }
    }
});

var view = new View({el: button1});
view.setElement(button2);

button1.trigger('click'); 
button2.trigger('click');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/S7A9z/

That should give you something like this in the console:

```
button1 jQuery <button id=​"button1">​</button>​
button2 jQuery <button id=​"button2">​</button>​
Backbone <button id=​"button2">​</button>​ true
```

Both raw jQuery event handlers will be triggered as expected but we'll only get the `button2` event through Backbone because the `setElement` call happened before the `trigger` calls.

So why is `view.el === e.target` true? Well, you're clicking on `button2` so `e.target` will be `button2` and the `view.setElement(button2)` call replaces `view.el` so `this.el` inside the Backbone `click` handler will also be `button2`.